# How to make on() 'click' function run indefinitely?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to set up a chat interface and I've written a function that displays an `<ul>`'s `<li>`s in another `<ul>`. The function runs as wanted but only once. That is, it still toggles the elements class every time it gets clicked, but it doesn't append the `<li>`s.

```
<div class="m_window">
<div class="m_contacts">
<% a.forEach(function(hombre){ %>
  <ul class="message">Messages received from <%= hombre.username %>
    <% message.forEach(function(message){ %>
        <% if(message.sender.id.equals(hombre.id) && message.receiver.id.equals(currentUser._id)){%>
          <li><%= message.text %></li>
        <% } %>
    <% }); %>
  </ul>
<% }); %>
</div>
<div class="m_chat">
  <ul class="list2">
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

**This is the jquery function**

```
  $('body').on('click', '.message', function() {
    $('.list2').empty();
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('.list2').append($('.selected > li'));
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
});
```

The way it works is, you click on a `<ul>`(contact) to display its messages. you click on another contact and it does the same thing. But once I click on an already 'visited' contact it doesn't display the messages any longer? 
**Why does it append the messages only once per `<ul>`?**

Comment: you are making list2 empty always whenever you click on ul `$('.list2').empty();`, remove this code and you should see what you expect

Comment: I pass the empty() function in order to 'refresh' and get a clean chat window every time I click on different contacts.

Comment: If I remove` empty()`, it still would append only once..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The listener is triggered on each click but you move the `.selected` messages to `.list2`. So the second click will do nothing because the `<li>s` of the `<ul>` are gone.

So you can make a `clone()` and then `appendTo(...)`

For a working example see the runnable one below or here : https://codesandbox.io/s/mqjw9jpj0j

For the jQuery doc on clone : https://codesandbox.io/s/mqjw9jpj0j

> As shown in the discussion for .append(), normally when an element is inserted somewhere in the DOM, it is moved from its old location.

```js
$("body").on("click", ".message", function() {
  $(".list2").empty();
  $(this).addClass("selected");
  // if we do not clone to node is move
  // so no more in ul.messages
  // and so the next move will move nothing
  // see here : https://api.jquery.com/clone/
  $(".selected > li")
    .clone()
    .appendTo(".list2");
  // $(".list2").append($(".selected > li"));
  $(this).removeClass("selected");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="m_window">
    <div class="m_contacts">
      <ul class="message">Messages received from Foo
        <li>
          Hello
        </li>
        <li>
          Another message
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="message">Messages received from Bar
        <li>
          Hello from Bar
        </li>
        <li>
          Bar message
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="m_chat">
      <ul class="list2">
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Please include all relevant code here on Stack Overflow, not only on an external site. You can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to provide a runnable example here.

Comment: Thanks I will check this :)